# remote server connect with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I have mysql 5.1 set up and running.

I need to connect to:

location: comm.eng.bxg.com

name: amntxy

user: username

pswd: password

I have tried using

mysql -h amntxy -u username -p

Also tried: use amntxy and use comm.eng.bxg.com/amntxy

But I am unable to connect.

I get the following error:

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host

I also tried mysql_connect but keep getting the error : mysql_connect is not recognized as internal or external command

But I do not understand hwo I can connect here.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -h comm.eng.bxg.com -u username -p
```

After this it will ask for a password.

Optionally you can also directly specify the database name that you want:

```
mysql -h comm.eng.bxg.com -u username -p db_name
```

But again, this is 100% optional. You will be able to select or change it after with the command `USE db_name`.

Comment: Thank you :)
But still not luck :( The first command does not seem to get to connected.
I can just connect to mysql on my machine.
db_ name in this case is amntxy. So using the second command i do not get option to specify password. So end up getting same error message "ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host".

Comment: @jil: make sure you can connect to comm.eng.bxg.com, try for example to ping it from the command line: `ping comm.eng.bxg.com`